# Excel sum two non-adjacent cells ignoring NA error

Tags: sum, excel-formula

This is really simple, but I can't find the correct solution.

I have two cells A1 and D1 that I need to add together, however one or both of them may contain NA errors (to prevent plotting on a graph). I need to find the total of these two cells, or if one is NA it must return the non-NA value :
eg : 100+NA=100 or NA+100=100 or 100+100=200

I have tried =SUMIF(Range_1,"<>#NA") but as this is not a range I can't get the right answer and I have tried combinations of if(iserror formula with no success... help !!

Comment: I've found that =IF(ISERROR(A1),D1,IF(ISERROR(D1),A1,A1+D1)) works, is there a better way ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good thing that you found a solution yourself.
An even easier way (IMHO - from a legibility point of view) might be to use

```
=IFERROR(A1; 0) + IFERROR(D1; 0)
```

This way you still perform a simple addition operation, but include the required conditionality.

IFERROR() is a convenience function that combines the functionality of the IF() function and the ISERROR() function; it avoids having to state the same formula twice when using only the IF() function.

Comment: not only is it a convenience function, it's also optimized for specific cases, so it handles quicker than using `IF(ISERROR(`

Answer (score 3):

I found the `=IFNA` formula to work faster.

In your example, it would be `=IFNA(A1,D1)` - if `A1` is not `NA` it'll return the value, otherwise will return `D1`. It means that if both `A1` and `D1` are `NA`, that will be the output.

Hope this helps!